# Delphi read Excel file with a column with mixed data types

Tags: excel, delphi, ado

We have an excel file we are trying to read into an ADOTable in Delphi.
The first column contains mostly integers and sometimes it will have a char; we would like to read the whole column as type text.

The problem is the char data is being read in as null (not an 'n' its actual value).
There is only 1 'n' it is the last row and there are 13 other rows with integers and 1 header row; the values in the rows are coming back as integers; except for the 'n', which is returned as null.

Here is the code to read that value:
var1 := DM.ExcelTable.FieldByName(cb1.Text).Value;
var1 is variant so it it can hold an integer or string

Here is what I tried after researching:

- Even with this in the connection string (IMEX)
  Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
  it still returns null (for the char 'n')
- Also noticed, when setting the connection string at runtime, when connected is set to True, the
  connection string gets changed, and the IMEX setting was gone.
- Was able to read that whole column as type text (not integer), if 5 rows of dummy data,     containing text, were inserted at the top, right under the header.

We would like to read the data in that column as text not integer, and without the dummy data inserted at the top if possible. How can that be done, please?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. (Please read the previous link, to understand what you need to provide).

Answer (score 0):

This worked after all:
“Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"

Just needed to get the column headers manually.